# How do I use a self signed cert in ios6?

Tags: ssl, ios6

I'm using iOS 6

I'm trying to run a web service with a self signed cert that I created, and having an iOS 6 device to successfully use it.

I'm using SHA256 to generate and sign the certs.  I've read on the Internet that iOS 6 devices reject certs created with MD5

Here I make my rootCA:

```
% openssl genrsa -des3 -out private/rootCA.key 2048
```

Then I signed it:

```
% openssl req -x509 -sha256 -new -nodes -key private/rootCA.key -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

Then I convert it to p12 format, so that I can put in my iOS 6 device:

```
% openssl pkcs12 -export -in rootCA.pem -inkey private/rootCA.key -out rootCA.p12
```

Then in Macosx I added rootCA.p12 to my keychain with Keychain Access.

Then I made a cert for my server:

```
% openssl genrsa -out mydemo.com.key 2048
```

Then I made a signing request

```
% openssl req -sha256 -new -key mydemo.com.key -out mydemo.com.csr
```

Then I signed it:

```
% openssl x509 -sha256 -req -in mydemo.com.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey private/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mydemo.com.crt -days 500
```

Then I used mydemo.com.crt in nginx.

Macosx Chrome and Safari thought the cert was valid.

I added rootCA.p12 to my iOS device.  I can see it in Profiles.

Security Framework on the iOS 6 device rejects the cert.

What do I do?